# simple CSS switcher and save cookie

Tags: html, css, cookies

I want to create a button that can switch between stylesheets (example below) and I would like for it to create a cookie so that the browser remembers and saves the setting.

```
<button id="style1">Light</button>
<button id="style2">Dark</button>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
```

The simpler the code the better. Thank you!

Comment: Thats not possible..

Comment: @Dsafds then explain that in the answer.  Not sure if it was you or someone else, but the downvote for the question was not necessary; the question is quite clear.  We can't expect the questioner to understand the implications of a solution fully, otherwise they wouldn't ask.

Comment: You would need to use PHP for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to set and get the cookie and change the style based on that.

switch1.php

```
<?php
setcookie("s", "1");
header("Location: index.html");
?>
```

switch2.php

```
<?php
setcookie("s", "2");
header("Location: index.html");
?>
```

index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
<?php 
if isset($_COOKIE["s"]))
    echo '"style' . $_COOKIE["s"] . '.css"';
else
    echo '"style1.css"';
?>
>
<button id="style1"><a href="switch1.php">Light</a></button>
<button id="style2"><a href="switch2.php">Dark</a></button>
```

Comment: Iv'e tried this and can't seem to get this working. Is there is a simpler method maybe something with jquery or javascript? Also sidenote, I'm trying to use this with wordpress.